# Way to pass arguments into deferRelSeq method

Tags: scala, graphql, relayjs, sangria

Is there a way to pass the query arguments into `deferRelSeq` method and get the arguments in one of the anonymous functions that is passed into `Fetcher.rel`?
Here, I want to get the `ConnectionArgs` in the anonymous function and use them to prepare a `sangria.relay.Connection`.

Comment: No, not really. Fetch API was designed for simple ID and relation ID fetching. For more complex scenarios I would recommend to implement `DeferredResolver` directly. You also should be able to use it in combination with Fetch API (they are not mutually exclusive)

Comment: Okay, I'll implement `DeferredResolver` directly. Thank you.